# MySQL - UPDATE or INSERT if exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database that needs to be updated if an instance does not already exist. I have tried the following methods but are no closer to a solution:

```
SET @last_message_id = (
SELECT id FROM mailbox_last_message WHERE conversationId = '13'
);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE mailbox_last_message SET conversationId = '13', initiatorMessageId = '20', interlocutorMessageId = '10' 
WHERE id = @last_message_id 
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
INSERT INTO  mailbox_last_message (  id ,  conversationId ,  initiatorMessageId ,  interlocutorMessageId ) 
VALUES ('' , '13', '20', '0' );
COMMIT;
```

And this one:

```
 SET @last_message_id = (
 SELECT `id` FROM mailbox_last_message WHERE `conversationId` = 13);

 INSERT INTO  mailbox_last_message (  id ,  conversationId ,  initiatorMessageId ,  interlocutorMessageId ) 
 VALUES ( '', '13', '20', '0' ) ON DUPLICATE 
 KEY UPDATE id = @last_message_id
```

This solution creates a new instance with conversationId 13 which is not what I want. I've tried to search the documentation and various tutorials/examples online but I can't find any suitable solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use INSERT IGNORE INTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique index on the fields that you want to keep unique, you can use INSERT IGNORE INTO syntax

```
    SET @last_message_id = (
SELECT id FROM mailbox_last_message WHERE conversationId = '13'
);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO  mailbox_last_message (  id ,  conversationId ,  initiatorMessageId ,  interlocutorMessageId ) 
    VALUES ('' , '13', '20', '0' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = @last_message_id;
```

Comment: This solution also inserts a new row and does not update the one that already exists. `conversationId` is not an unique key but `id` is.

Comment: If I modify your solution with `VALUES (@last_message_id , '13', '20', '0' )` than I achive what I need. Thx for pointing me in right direction.